# ASP.Net MVC Recursive Model with Parent ID

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, recursion, model, ef-code-first, foreign-keys

I can't seem to find an answer to this, so hopefully someone can help. I have the following model that can be nested within other items of the same model, effectively creating an n-tier dataset. My model is written as follows:

```
public partial class Resource
{
  [Key]
  public int ResourceID { get; set; }
  [Display(Name = "Parent Resource")]
  public int? ParentResourceID { get; set; }
  public virtual Resource ParentResource { get; set; 
  [Display(Name = "Resource Name")]
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public bool Deleted { get; set; }
}
```

ParentResourceID can be set to NULL, meaning that the item is on Level 1 and has no parents.

However, when I request an item from the database that has a parent resource assigned to it, the ParentResource object is always empty.

I tried a multitude of [ForeignKey] and [InverseProperty] ideas, but didn't have any luck.

Do I need to map something so that the model knows that ParentResourceID actual equals ResourceID for the virtual object, and if so, how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I would use the [Fluent API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh295844%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) to configure this. It is a lot more flexible than using the attributes on your entity properties.  It would look something like this.

```
 this.HasOptional(l => l.ParentResource)
  .WithMany(p => p.Children)
  .HasForeignKey(l => l.ParentId);
```

What is not clear from your model is whether a parent can have multiple children.  Assuming multiple children you need to add a property like this to your model.

```
public virtual List<Resource> Children {get; set;}
```